# Vector proxy const and non const operation

Tags: c++11, templates

I wrote a matrix template which is based on a `std::vector`. I am facing a problem when I want to proceed to an mathematical operation between two matrices: one which is a `const` reference and the other one which is not `const` and not a reference.

I am passing through a proxy to retrieve data stored in the `std::vector`:

```
template<typename T>
class Mat
{
public:
    typedef T                                   value_type;
    typedef T&                                  reference;
    typedef const T&                            const_reference;
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::size_type  size_type;

private:
    class Proxy
    {
    public:
        Proxy(Mat& o, value_type i) : o(o), i(i)
        {}

        operator value_type()
        { return o.m[i]; }

        reference operator=(const_reference other)
        { return o.m[i] = other; }

        reference operator+=(const_reference other)
        { return o.m[i] += other; }

        value_type operator*(const_reference other)
        { return o.m[i] * other; }

    private:
        Mat& o;
        size_type i;
    };

    // Matrix methods and operator overloads.

    Proxy operator[](size_type i)
    { return Proxy(*this, i); }

    const Proxy operator[](size_type i) const
    { return Proxy(*this, i); }
```

Here is a sample from an extract of a test class which triggered an error:

```
void Test::buildMemoryMatrix(const Mat<int>& state)
{
    Mat<int> t = state.getTransposed();
    for(Mat<int>::size_type i = 0; i < state.rows(); ++i)
    {
        for(Mat<int>::size_type j = 0; j < t.cols(); ++j)
        {
            for(Mat<int>::size_type k = 0; k < state.cols(); ++k)
            {
                if(i == j)
                { continue; }
                memory[i * memory.cols() + j] += state[i * state.cols() + k] * t[k * t.cols() + j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Some precisions about the `Mat<int>` methods and `Test` class members:

- The `memory` is a member of `Test`. It is represented as a `Mat<int>` object;
- `Mat::getTransposed()` returns a transposed of a matrix;
- `Mat::rows()` returns the number of rows of a matrix;
- `Mat::cols()` returns the number of columns of a matrix

The following line give me some trouble:

```
memory[i * memory.cols() + j] += state[i * state.cols() + k] * t[k * t.cols() + j];
```

> passing ‘const Mat::Proxy’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers
>   [-fpermissive]

How to solve this problem?
Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Ditch `Proxy` and `operator[]`. Use `operator()` instead.

Comment: @n.m. What are the benefits?

Comment: The benefits? Not having to deal with stuff that gets in the way and doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @n.m. Now I see the benefits :) thanks. However, was it possible to get to the desired result with a proxy?

Comment: I think you would have to define separate classes for `Proxy` and `ConstProxy`, perhaps using a template to factor out the commonality (`Proxy<Mat>` and `Proxy<const Mat>`). `const Proxy` doesn't quite work because you must have a constructor that accepts a `const Mat&`.